# How to manage long URL after @link tag for PHPDoc

Tags: php, netbeans, phpstorm, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I wanted to provide my PHPDoc block with a link to the existent documentation for a method parameter. So, I used a **@link** tag and put the URL after it. The problem is the URL is too long, and it doesn't look pleasant in my IDE. What would you suggest to manage such a situation, I mean to look the DocBlock pleasant or too shorten the URL somehow? URL leads to our internal wiki, and it includes Russian symbols which makes it even longer. We use PHPStorm and NetBeans as primary IDEs.

Comment: Create an alias/redirect page in the wiki https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Redirects

Comment: An alias is not a decision as it's another department that manages the wiki, and actually I would prefer some decision to have a full link after a @link tag but to show its shorter version in the ide or to wrap it

Comment: So use a different url shortener e.g. https://goo.gl/ there is no option in either of those IDEs to magically do it.